# Sending values to another function golang

Tags: function, go, struct

I made a random room program with 4 rooms. I'm trying to take the attributes in each room and pass them through to other functions. In each room is a person with a name and an age attribute. I'm trying to pass on those attributes to test against if statements to put out an additional response. How do I pass these values on?

```
//the random maze room game

package main


//All imports can be combined into ()
import ("fmt"
        //Import needed for random operation
        "math/rand"
        //Import requied to call upon current time 
        "time"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age int
}



func main(){
    // These two lines are designed to reset the random Seed every time the program is run 
    // Unless the randomizer is seeded, Golang 1.6 is pseudo-random, 
    // always defaulting to Seed(1) 
    s1 := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r1 := rand.New(s1)
    switch r1.Intn(4){
    case 0:
        westRoom()
    case 1:
        eastRoom()
    case 2:
        northRoom()
    case 3:
        southRoom()
    default:
        lostRoom()
    }

    p := Person{}
    p.Name = Avatarname
    p.Age = Avatarage
    avatar(&p)
    appearance(&p)  

}

func westRoom(){
    fmt.Println("You find yourself in a room with three walls, and a door behind you.")
    fmt.Println("The opposite wall is a window, overlooking the sea")
    Avatarname := "Bill"
    Avatarage := 25
    return
}

func eastRoom(){
    fmt.Println("You find yourself in a room with a door on the walls to your left, right, and behind you")
    fmt.Println("on the wall across from you is a painting of a mountain scene")
    Avatarname := "Mary"
    Avatarage := 33
    return
}

func northRoom(){
    fmt.Println("You find yourself in a room with a door on the wall behind you")
    fmt.Println("You see several statues of people standing around the room")
    Avatarname := "Joe"
    Avatarage := 58
    return
}

func southRoom(){
    fmt.Println("You find yourself in a room with a door on the wall in front and behind you")
    Avatarname := "Abagail"
    Avatarage := 67
    return
}

func lostRoom(){
    fmt.Println("You are unable to find a room in a maze filled only with rooms")
    fmt.Println("It's almost like the programmer didn't know what he was doing")
}

func avatar(p.Name, p.Age){
    if p.Name == "Bill" || "Joe" {
        fmt.Println("You see a man standing in the middle of the room")
    }   else {
        fmt.Println("You see a woman standing in the middle of the room")
    }
}

func appeareance(p.Name, p.Age) {
    if p.Age > 50 {
        fmt.Println("They look old")
    }   else {
        fmt.Println("They look young")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to change your room functions to return either a `Person` struct or the attributes of the `Person` struct.

Check out the live code here: <kbd>[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/N4MvDlbf56)</kbd>

For example,

```
func northRoom() *Person{
  fmt.Println("You find yourself in a room with a door on the wall behind you")
  fmt.Println("You see several statues of people standing around the room")
  return &Person{"Joe", 58}
}
```

Now the function calls in your `switch` statement can expect a `Person` struct being returned.

```
var p *Person
switch r1.Intn(4){
case 0:
    p = westRoom()
case 1:
    p = eastRoom()
case 2:
    p = northRoom()
case 3:
    p = southRoom()
default:
    p = lostRoom()
}

avatar(p)
appearance(p)
```

Note that you will need to change the signature of your `avatar()` and `appearance()` functions to accept a `*Person` parameter.

Comment: This helped. Before this I tried this in each return, I was getting a syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline, expected comma or }. Part A fixed that by placing the address symbol and the simplified information in the brackets. I'll start working on Part B now

Comment: @as.beaulieu I updated my answer with a link to Go Playground. In my example, I returned a `nil` in the `lostRoom()` function and make sure that the `avatar()` and `appearance()` functions check for that. You can decide how you want to handle that case.

Comment: @as.beaulieu Please consider marking this answer as accepted, if it resolved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your room functions return a `Person`?  Example:

```
func main() {
    // These two lines are designed to reset the random Seed every time the program is run
    // Unless the randomizer is seeded, Golang 1.6 is pseudo-random,
    // always defaulting to Seed(1)
    s1 := rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())
    r1 := rand.New(s1)

    var p Person
    switch r1.Intn(4) {
    case 0:
        p = westRoom()
    case 1:
        p = eastRoom()
    case 2:
        p = northRoom()
    case 3:
        p = southRoom()
    default:
        lostRoom()
    }

    p.printAvatar()
    p.printAppeareance()

}

func westRoom() Person {
    fmt.Println("You find yourself in a room with three walls, and a door behind you.")
    fmt.Println("The opposite wall is a window, overlooking the sea")

    return Person{
        Name: "Bill",
        Age:  25,
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9_PuPsRdXg